# After revouninstller removal of Kite, spyder attempts to open but then stops. No error messages are given. How to fix or reinstall?

Tags: spyder

Anaconda3 was installed with spyder included.
I uninstalled Kite using revouninstaller.
Now spyder will not open.
I reset spyder settings to defaults using
`spyder --reset` at anaconda base prompt.
It still will not open.
How to fix or uninstall?

Comment: What Spyder version are you using? If is not the latest (currently 5.3.1) I would suggest you to try to install the latest version by creating a new conda env using the conda-forge channel. You can do that by running something like `conda create -n spyder-cf -c conda-forge spyder` from the Anaconda prompt. Then try activating the new env (running `conda activate spyder-cf`) and then running from it the new Spyder installation with `spyder`

Comment: Should I attempt to uninstall spyder first? What syntax should I use for spider 5? That is as much as the open screen tells me -version 5. The installation was very messy, I am considering uninstalling anaconda completely.  Do you recommend use of a clean package first before a complete uninstall?

Comment: Oh I see, then I would suggest to uninstall or try to force a reinstall of Spyder in your base environment (to uninstall use `conda remove spyder` or to force a reinstall `conda install -f spyder`). If that doesn't help I would say that uninstalling the Anaconda distribution could be worty. However, even after doing that, you will need to create a new env if you want to get the latest Spyder version available (which is only available through the conda-forge channel as pointed above). Also, just in case, if you want to check the packages versions you can run from an Anaconda prompt `conda list`